# Удаление определенных значений MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с проблемой - искал в гугле - не нашёл, скорее, из-за неправильной формулировки вопроса. Собственно сам вопрос.

Таблица на 1000 строк. Нужно отредактировать значение столбца "Описание".

В этом столбце хранятся текстовые значения: один, два, три, пять, сорок, девять.
Каким образом удалить СРАЗУ все значения из ВСЕХ СТРОК данного СТОЛБЦА, ЗА ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕМ значений: два, девять?

Всем большое спасибо!

Comment: у столбца есть только одно значение. то что вы спрашиваете к sql не имеет отношения.

Comment: всмысле не имеет? Тоесть мне это все снится, и у меня нет никакой бд, ни столбцов, ни строк?)
Сайт на движке dle, использует mysql для хранения данных,использую навикат в качестве клиента, если это упростит путь решения

Comment: @Михаил1313, "упростит путь решения" приведение вашей структуры к 3-й нормальной форме, @Alex Krass правильно все сказал. А с такой структурой надо гуглить "удаление гланд через...", в смысле можно, но ответ на такой вопрос не приносит пользы начинающим программистам, только плодит горе-хирургов...

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE (название таблицы) SET (название столбца) = 0 WHERE (название столбца) != '2,9';

Comment: UPDATE dle_post SET tags = 0 WHERE tags != '1979,1984,1992,1993,1994,1995,1997,1998,1999,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,Австралия,Австрия,Бельгия,Болгария,Босния-Герцеговина,Великобритания,Венгрия,Германия,Гонконг,Дания,Индия,Индонезия,Ирландия,Испания,Италия,Канада,Китай,Люксембург,Мексика,Новая Зеландия,Норвегия,ОАЭ,Польша,Россия,Румыния,Cербия,США,Тайвань,Тунис,Турция,Украина,Франция,Чехия,Швейцария,Швеция,ЮАР,Япония';

Сделал, но удалилось все, остались только нули

Comment: То, что ты указал, должно сохраниться, а остальное удаляем?

Comment: да, то что указал,должно сохранится, а все остальное надо удалить

Comment: ... WHERE tags NOT IN (1979,1984,1992...)

Comment: Все равно ошибка
[SQL] UPDATE dle_post SET tags = NULL WHERE tags NOT IN (1979,1984,1992,1993,1994,1995,1997,1998,1999,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,Австралия,Австрия,Бельгия,Болгария,Босния-Герцеговина,Великобритания,Венгрия,Германия,Гонконг,Дания,Индия,Индонезия,Ирландия,Испания,Италия,Канада,Китай,Люксембург,Мексика, Новая-Зеландия, Норвегия, ОАЭ, Польша, Россия, Румыния, Cербия,США,Тайвань,Тунис,Турция,Украина,Франция,Чехия,Швейцария,Швеция,ЮАР,Япония)

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'Австралия' in 'where clause'

Comment: Попробуйте экранировать ('1979,1984,1992...')

Comment: Тоесть, я неправильно понял, то что вы указываете, это содержимое одной ячейки?

Comment: @cyber_bober, насколько я понял, да, у него там в одной ячейке [список значений, разделенных запятыми](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV).

Answer (score 2):

Могу вам только посочувствовать.

При построении баз данных есть такое понятие, как нормальные формы. При их игнорировании, операции выборки или изменения данных приводят к логическим ошибкам. Так вот, ваша база не удовлетворяется даже самой первой (базовой) нормальной форме, которая гласит: каждая ячейка содержит ровно одно логическое значение и больше ничего. А поскольку вы туда запихнули несколько логических значений, то и просто так манипулировать данными через SQL будет либо затруднительно, либо невозможно.

В данном случае надо будет cтроить достаточно сложный запрос, если вы хотите сделать это только через SQL или даже воспользоваться процедурным расширением SQL/PSM(хранимые процедуры mysql). Но лучше разбить его на три простых запроса. Но в этом случае я не могу гарантировать правильный результат, так как могут быть проблемы с подстроками искомых тегов.

```
UPDATE %Table% SET %Row% = 'два, девять' WHERE %Row% LIKE '%два%' AND %Row% LIKE '%девять%';
UPDATE %Table% SET %Row% = 'два' WHERE %Row% LIKE '%два%' AND %Row% NOT LIKE '%девять%';
UPDATE %Table% SET %Row% = 'девять' WHERE %Row% NOT LIKE '%два%' AND %Row% LIKE '%девять%';
```

P.S. основная проблема в данном варианте в том, что паттерн поиска %девять% так же подходит и для тегов "сорок девять", "девятьсот" и т.д. где есть упоминание девятки.